# Using Magnific Popup inside Justified Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, magnific-popup

I'm attempting to use [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) inside [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.com/projects/justified-gallery/), and I'm having trouble. It doesn't seem to be picking up the anchor tags that I want it to work on, and clicking an image just ends up going straight to the href location.

I know it's working on the page, because if I hand write some vanilla markup, it works fine:

```
<a class="gallery-image" href="http://localpath/imagelarge.jpg">
    <img src="http://localpath/imagethumb.jpg">
</a>
```

However, since I'm using Justified Gallery, the markup generated isn't quite the same:

```
<div class="justifiedGallery" id="gallery">
    <div class="jg-row" style="height: 128px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
        <div class="jg-image" style="left: 0px;">
             <a class="gallery-image" href="http://localpath/imagelarge.jpg">
                 <img style="width: 192px; height: 128px; display: inline; opacity: 1;" alt="undefined" src="http://localpath/imagethumb.jpg">
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript that I'm using for both the working sample and the none working one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#gallery").justifiedGallery({
            'usedSuffix': 'lt240',
            'justifyLastRow': false,
            'rowHeight': 120,
            'fixedHeight': false,
            'captions': false,
            'margins': 1
        });

        $('.gallery-image').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I did have to tweak Justified Gallery in order to add the gallery-image class, but everything else is stock.

I'm thinking that there's something conflicting, but I can't seem to track it down.

Has anybody used these two before? Is there something wrong with the way I'm initializing Magnific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add just:

```
$("#gallery").justifiedGallery({
        'usedSuffix': 'lt240',
        'justifyLastRow': false,
        'rowHeight': 120,
        'fixedHeight': false,
        'captions': false,
        'margins': 1
    }).magnificPopup({type:'image', delegate: '.gallery-image'});
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. BTW, Magnific is the best lightbox I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't use the Justified Gallery plugin before, but as i can see, your markup is correct. I bet, there is a situation during gallery initializing,

Gallery plugin may manipulate DOM, so i suggest to bind magnific popup when gallery finishes its initializing, you can use **onComplete** (Justified Gallery) callback.